# Setting the value of the SOPITEM. Text field using SDO v29

Tags: sage50

I'd like it confirmed that this is a bug, (and that hopefully Sage will fix it).

I want to set the TEXT field of a special S3 line item when posting a SOPItem to a sales order (SalesRecord):

From the docs:

[image: Sage 50 SDO docs extract: Posting a Sales Order]

I have it all working fine as is, however when I add the following line:

```
SDOHelper.Write(oSopItem, "TEXT", (String)"Text Test");
```

Nothing comes through in that field within the Sage50 order.

When I read in an existing Sage50 sales order with SDO and use

```
string text = (string)SDOHelper.Read(oSopItem, "TEXT");
```

The value returns the same as the description:

```
string descr = (string)SDOHelper.Read(oSopItem, "DESCRIPTION");
```

However when I query the relevant record in the SOP_ITEM table using a direct ODBC connection, the expected value is indeed there in the TEXT column (as displayed in the Sage50 desktop UI).

I'm guessing this is a bug and the mapping is just plain wrong in the SDO?

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

oSopItem.Text is a property on the object, so it is not addressed in the same way as other fields.

Also from the docs:

[image]